# Including same jar in two modules throws a build error

Tags: java, android

I have an app with a main module ("app") and another module ("navigation").
Both modules have a dependency to a certain jar lib.
On top of that the app module also has a dependency to the navigation module.

Somehow it seems that this is a problem- I am getting following build error:

> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present:
>   com.google.common.base.Absent","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
>   :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForProductionDebug
>   FAILED :app:buildInfoGeneratorProductionDebug FAILURE: Build failed
>   with an exception.
>   * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForProductionDebug'.
>
> > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/0.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/1.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/2.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/3.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/4.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/5.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/6.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/7.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/8.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/9.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/10.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/14.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/15.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/16.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/17.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/18.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/20.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/22.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/23.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/24.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/25.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/26.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/29.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/30.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/31.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/32.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/33.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/34.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/35.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/36.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/37.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/38.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/39.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/40.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/41.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/42.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/43.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/44.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/45.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/46.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/47.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/48.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/49.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/50.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/51.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/52.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/53.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/54.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/55.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/56.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/57.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/61.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/62.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/63.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/64.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/65.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/66.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/67.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/68.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/69.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/70.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/71.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/72.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/75.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/77.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/79.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/80.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/81.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/82.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/83.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/84.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/85.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/86.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/87.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/88.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/89.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/90.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/91.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/92.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/93.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/94.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/95.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/96.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/97.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/98.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/99.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/100.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/101.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/102.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/103.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/104.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/105.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/106.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/107.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/108.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/109.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/110.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/111.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/112.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/113.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/114.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/115.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/116.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/117.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/118.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/119.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/120.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/121.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/122.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/123.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/124.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/125.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/126.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/127.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/128.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/129.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/130.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/131.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/132.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/133.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/134.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/135.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/136.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/137.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/138.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/139.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/140.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/141.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/142.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/143.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/144.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/145.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/146.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/147.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/148.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/149.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/150.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/151.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/152.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/153.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/154.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/155.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/156.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/157.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/158.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/159.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/160.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/161.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/162.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/163.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/164.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/165.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/166.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/167.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/168.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/169.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/170.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/171.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/172.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/173.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/174.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/175.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/176.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/177.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/178.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/179.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/180.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/181.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/182.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/183.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/184.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/185.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/186.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/187.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/188.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/189.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/190.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/191.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/192.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/193.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/194.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/195.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/196.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/197.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/198.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/199.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/200.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/201.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/202.jar,
> >     /path/myapp-x-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/production/debug/203.jar
> >     Learn how to resolve the issue at
> >     https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
> >     Program type already present: com.google.common.base.Absent

Comment: The link in the error message says to remove the app's dependence on the jar lib. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, but then my app module is not able to locate the jar's classes anymore :(